# FadeIn//FadeOut some quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my quotes in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/29/) to have a fade in/out effect when the plus button is clicked. I've read up on it and looked at similar projects but can't figure it out.

I tried adding this (get ready to laugh at my attempt) but it of course [broke the damn thing](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/31/):

```
$("#random-quote").click(function() { 
    $("#main-quote").fadeOut(300);
    $("#main-quote").fadeIn(300);
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like the text to fade out before changing, you can use the fadeout function which looks like this:

**FadeOut**

```
$("#main-quote").fadeOut(300, function() {});
```

You can wrap your `$('#main-quote').text();` changes in this, and then call `fadeIn();` at the end:

**jQuery**

```
$("#main-quote").fadeOut(300, function() {
  $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote);
  var selectedBG = selectedQuote.background;
  var selectedMovie = selectedQuote.movie;
  console.log(selectedBG);
  console.log(selectedMovie);
  $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + selectedBG + "')");


  $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote);
  var selectedMovie = selectedQuote.movie;
  console.log(selectedMovie);
  $("#what-movie").html(selectedMovie);
  $("#main-quote").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Also, for this to work, you need to remove your `$('#random-quote').click(getQuote);` line, which was making the background change twice because you're calling the same click function twice.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/35/)

Comment: Thanks also for explaining the background image change problem!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `css` `transition` for `background-image` at `body`; also removed `$('#random-quote').click(getQuote);`

```
  transition: background-image 200ms ease-in-out;
```

javascript

```
function getQuote() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    var selectedQuote = quotes[randomIndex];
    // `.fadeOut` here
    $('#main-quote').fadeOut(200).text(selectedQuote.quote);
    var selectedBG = selectedQuote.background;
    console.log(selectedBG);
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + selectedBG + "')");
    // `.fadeIn` here
    $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote).fadeIn(200);
    var selectedMovie = selectedQuote.movie;
    console.log(selectedMovie);
    $("#what-movie").html(selectedMovie);
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/36/

Answer (score 1):

Try fadeOut the entire box and after that run the function to change the text:

```
$('#main-box').fadeOut(800,function(){
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('" + selectedBG + "')");
    $('#main-quote').text(selectedQuote.quote);
    $(this).fadeIn(500)
});
```

Also to make "smooth" the background change use `transition`:

```
body {
    transition:all .3s linear;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/34/)

---

<sub>**Note:** I've also removed the click bind to the function  `getQuote()`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS3.

```css
.btn {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  color:white;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.btn:active {
  opacity: 0;
 }
```

```html
<button class="btn">RAND</button>
```

Comment: I meant the quote box, though I'm glad I got help for the background too!